# Angular Sorting Table Nasted Array of Objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

trying to get the best way to sort this array by property value.

```
"data": [
    {
      "id": "1913209a-4b96-4e9f-9377-17cc86cd4465",
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "mid_serial",
          "data": {
            "editable": false,
            "value": "5.65.2.88 - 12338456",
            "required": false,
            "type": "text"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "status",
          "data": {
            "editable": false,
            "value": "warning",
            "required": false,
            "type": "text"
          }
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "1913209a-4b96-4e9f-9377-17cc86cd4465",
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "mid_serial",
          "data": {
            "editable": false,
            "value": "5.65.2.88 - 12338456",
            "required": false,
            "type": "text"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "status",
          "data": {
            "editable": false,
            "value": "warning",
            "required": false,
            "type": "text"
          }
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
    ...        
  ]
```

So I'll pass the "name" property and the array must be sorted by the corresponding "value" property val. (it can also be reversed but that's easy)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are expected results? In order to group the sub arrays you would need to map them to flatter array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Javascript sort function adding a custom comparator. The code would be:

```
$scope.name = 'status' // Example

data.sort(function(a, b) {
   var aValue, bValue;
   a.data.forEach(function(element) { // Search the value
       if ($scope.name == element.name) aValue = element.data.value;
   }
   b.data.forEach(function(element) { // Search the value
       if ($scope.name == element.name) bValue = element.data.value;
   }
   return aValue - bValue; // Compare them in order to order the array
})
```

Try it and tell me something, I can't test it right now.